# Using SharePoint's lists.asmx and UpdateListItems to delete an item by Guid or UniqueId

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, wss-3.0, caml

I am trying to call the lists.asmx UpdateListItems() to delete a list item by unique id or guid.  The following batch xml fails with "Invalid URL Parameter. The URL provided contains an invalid Command or Value. Please check the URL again".

```
<Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1" ViewName="">
  <Method ID="1" Cmd="Delete">
    <Field Name="Guid">7be4a863ce-08de-4506-9c69-400749860e76</Field>
  </Method>
</Batch>
```

In addition, I have tried with and without enclosing "{}", UrlEncoding, using UniqueId instead of Guid, prefixing the guid with "[id];#", etc.  but to no avail.

Using the ID will work, but I would prefer using the Guid if possible:

```
<Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1" ViewName="">
  <Method ID="1" Cmd="Delete">
    <Field Name="ID">29</Field>
  </Method>
</Batch>
```

Anyone have any ideas, or is this not possible using the UniqueID or Guid?

Comment: Have you tried with GUID in all capitals?  It may not make a difference, but worth trying.

Comment: Peter, yes, tried all caps and it does not make a difference (in fact tried several of the ToString() format overrides for Guid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28office.12%29.aspx), they only give an example using ID... which leads me to believe it probably will not work with anything else.

Comment: Seems like this is not possible.  As Kit states, the docs (which are very weak in this area) only use ID as examples.  Chalking this up to not supported.